# Insert from multiple related tables during database migrating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm migrating Oracle DB to SQL Server via linked servers. Here is my question;

I have table on Oracle like this:

**OldPersonelTable**

```
PERSONID SSN  COUNTRY   CITY
-------------------------------
   1     123  RUSSIA    MOSCOW
   2     124  TURKEY    ISTANBUL
   3     125  TURKEY    ANKARA
```

And on my new SQL Server database I have tables like this:

**CountryTable**

```
COUNTRYID COUNTRYNAME
---------------------    
1         RUSSIA
2         TURKEY
```

**CITYTABLE**

```
CITYID COUNTRYID CITYNAME
-------------------------    
1          1      MOSCOW
2          2      ISTANBUL
3          2      ANKARA
```

**NewPersonelTable**

```
PERSONID SSN  COUNTRY   CITY
1        123   1          1
2        124   2          2
3        125   2          3
```

Yes that's all. I just wanna write a insert query selects from OldDatabase and insert into new personel table. Old db does not have any city and country id table. Only chance to join is as you see city and country names.

edit:Citynames are not unique.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Do you have CountryTable and city table in oracle?

Comment: unfortunately i dont. i just names in oldPersonelTable and country and city tables are on my new db. I'm trying to keep that columns with their ids on newPersonelTable..Thanks also as i said below citynames are not unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CITYTABLE` and `CountryTable` are already populated, you can populate `NewPersonelTable` like this:

If PERSONID is the primary key of NewPersonelTable, then you'll probably need to do:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

then run:

```
INSERT INTO NewPersonelTable ( PERSONID, SSN, COUNTRY, CITY )
SELECT T.PERSONID, T.SSN, C.COUNTRYID, CITY.CITYID
FROM OldPersonelTable T JOIN CountryTable C ON
  T.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRYNAME JOIN CITYTABLE CITY ON
  T.CITY = CITY.CITYNAME AND
  C.COUNTRYID = CITY.COUNTRYID
```

Comment: I already have Country and City tables but selecting from OldpersonelTable with city and country ids is problem

Comment: Thanks but there is one issue more. citynames are not unique but countrynames are absolutely unique

Comment: @Gokay Made a further edit to join through `CountryTable` for `CITY` matching

Answer (score 0):

Doing this migration task required to be in two steps:
1- Copy the main data
2- Copy the relational data

Be sure first that the new tables primary keys are IDENTITY.
As follows:
1) Copy Data

```
INSERT INTO CountryTable(COUNTRYNAME)
SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY FROM OraLink...OldPersonelTable

INSERT INTO CityTable(CITYNAME)
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM OraLink...OldPersonelTable

INSERT INTO NewPersonelTable(SSN)
SELECT DISTINCT SSN FROM OraLink...OldPersonelTable
```

2) Copy Relations

```
UPDATE CityTable SET COUNTRYID=CountryTable.COUNTRYID 
FROM OraLink...OldPersonelTable O INNER JOIN CountryTable
ON O.Country=CountryTable.COUNTRYNAME
WHERE CITYNAME=City

UPDATE NewPersonelTable SET COUNTRY=CountryTable.COUNTRYID, CITY=CityTable.CITYID
FROM OraLink...OldPersonelTable O INNER JOIN CountryTable
ON O.Country=CountryTable.COUNTRYNAME
INNER JOIN CityTable ON O.CITY=CityTable.CITYNAME
WHERE NewPersonelTable.SSN=O.SSN
```